# PrImary key or foreign key for a m-to-n relation table

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I have a table in my database that models a m-to-n relation. The primary key of this relation is of course the combined primary keys of the 2 entities involved in this relation.

The relation goes like this: m customers have n orders

```
create table customer(
cid             SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
...
);


create table order(
oid             SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
...
);


create table has(
oid             INTEGER REFERENCES order(oid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
cid             INTEGER REFERENCES customer(cid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (oid,cid) or PRIMARY KEY (oid,cid)
);
```

I'm a bit confused on what to use here: primary key or foreign key to put them in relation?

thanks in advance for any help.

Jaiel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `PRIMARY KEY` for the composite key in table `has`.  The combination of the order and customer IDs in the `has` table is a primary key in that table, because it allows the identification of a unique single record.

Note that both `oid` and `cid` in table `has` are *foreign* keys, pointing to the `order` and `customer` tables, respectively.

Comment: thank you. foreign key gave me a failure but primary key didnt like you said :D